# How do I convert a date retrieved by API to a date understood by React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datetime

In my app, I retrieve time from API in a format like this : 2020-08-31T15:05:10.768904Z and I'm trying to compare this date with the current Date().

What is the best way to calculate difference between the two.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried *anything*? You've got an ISO date and you can get a current client-side date with `new Date()`.

Comment: I've tried Date().toLocaleString() which gives me :8/31/2020, 4:19:32 PM but from there I cant think of anything except decomposing the string which would be mega hard. Also, Im not expecting Date() - myvariable to work.

Comment: Create a Date instance from your string.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, that's not in comment because I cant yet. You have to decompose it and i would use regex to get it.

Comment: There's no reason to employ a regular expression; the date format is ISO standard.